# SOAP webservice

Tags: java, web-services, webservice-client

I am trying to create the web services client and for that generated the proxy classes using wsdl file.
After that i follow the below steps:

1. created the service class object
2. using service class got the associated port
3. invoking the service method on the port object.

My services class(server side code) signature is something like this:

```
public javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement validateAddress(javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement validateAddress){

    .......

    return SOAPElement ;
}
```

my problem is i don't have any idea how to create SOAPElement object to call this method as well as after receiving SOAPElement as a result how to extract that to get the actual value.

can anybody help me on this...

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may follow this well written complete guide:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/tutorials/ws-jse/